# Ruby- Open and draw on pdf

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation

Is there a good gem to open a PDF and draw lines on it?  I've played around RMagick and prawn, both seem to only create new PDFs and not edit pre-existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you are after writing over a template RGhost may fit the bill as it can use  an eps file as a background image. Not writing over an existing PDF document OTOH. Then there may be a way to convert a PDF into an EPS file with ghostscript.

http://rghost.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html RGhost::Document.define_template

Comment: I used RGhost to convert my background image (a government form) to an EPS file and then it's easy to load it back in and write on top. The code is essentially this: RGhost::Convert.new('filename.pdf').to(:eps, :filename => 'filename.eps', :range => 1..1)

Answer (score 2):

iText can do it.

Here's someone wrestling with getting iText and Rjb to work together with his Ruby app:

http://blogs.thewehners.net/josh/posts/406-using-itext-to-generate-pdfs-in-rails-jruby-vs-ruby-java-bridge

Answer (score 0):

the combine_pdf gem can do it... although there aren't any drawing tools except the text-box (which you can use to create horizontal lines).

If it's something you can draw on a new PDF (say, using Prawn, as an example), then [combine_pdf can merge these two pdf files or stamp them one on top of the other](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf).

once you created your new pdf with the drawings, you could do something like this:

```
overlay = CombinePDF.parse prawn_pdf.render
merged_pdf = CombinePDF.load 'original.pdf'
merged_pdf.pages[0] << overlay.pages[0]
merged_pdf.save 'new_pdf.pdf'
```

That will work with one page. You can repeat or adapt to your needs.